# Warning: node.js detection failed, sbt will use the Rhino based Trireme JavaScript engine

Tags: node.js, playframework, rhino

I'm new to [Play framework](https://www.playframework.com/). Please explain the meaning of the below warning.

> Warning: node.js detection failed, sbt will use the Rhino based Trireme JavaScript engine instead to run JavaScript assets compilation, which in some cases may be orders of magnitude slower than using node.js

I don't want anything that slow down my application so please advice if I should change the JS Engine to Node.js, but my PlayFramework project is using Java on the server side.

Comment: https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.x/Assets#Managed-assets

Answer (score 11):

You need to install Node.js and then tell the sbt/java engine to use it.

```
  brew install node
```

Edit .bash_profile and add:

```
   export SBT_OPTS="${SBT_OPTS} -Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node -Dsbt.jse.command=$(which node)"
```

This eliminated the warning for me on OSX

Comment: Thanks. Works just fine without setting SBT_OPTS though.

Answer (score 5):

In Windows:

- Install [node.js](https://nodejs.org/en/download/)
- Go to *Control Panel - System and Security - System - Advanced system settings*
- Click *Environment Variables...*
- Search in *System variables* for `SBT_OPTS`

  - If such exists, click *Edit...* and concatenate `-Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node` to *Variable value*
  - If such does NOT exist, click *New...* and write `SBT_OPTS` to *Variable name* and `-Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node` to *Variable value*
- Click *OK* - *OK* - *OK*
- Restart any command prompt (cmd, PowerShell) that is currently running Play Framework

Answer (score 4):

in ubuntu

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup | sudo bash -

sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

then add as above to your .profile in your home directory

```
export SBT_OPTS="${SBT_OPTS} -Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node -Dsbt.jse.command=$(which node)"
```

then

```
 . ./.profile
```

to reload your .profile

For a more flexible install using node version manager check the following tutorial:
[how to install node js on an ubuntu 14.04 server](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-node-js-on-an-ubuntu-14-04-server)

Build again and the warning about using the Trireme stuff should be gone.

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to setting the environment variable, you can add this line to your build.sbt file:

```
JsEngineKeys.engineType := JsEngineKeys.EngineType.Node
```

See: https://github.com/sbt/sbt-js-engine

Answer (score 1):

sbt plugins requiring a JS engine are used only in the build process, and so missing Node.js only slows down assets building stages if you use any.

The built application is not affected.

Anyway, you may want to install node.js to your PATH, where it should be auto-detected.

Answer (score 0):

in Windows 10:

Install node.js from https://nodejs.org/en/
(The installer automatically adds node.js to your PATH)

then add:

```
export SBT_OPTS="$SBT_OPTS -Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node"
```

to your plugins.sbt in

```
. ./project/plugins.sbt
```

Worked for me - the warning has disappeared!

**EDIT:** 
Apparently plugins.sbt was the wrong place to add the

```
export SBT_OPTS="$SBT_OPTS -Dsbt.jse.engineType=Node"
```

...although the warning disappeared when loading my app, it led to an error when relaunching the app a couple of hours later:

> error: not found: value export

I would be glad if anyone could help and tell me where to put the export.

Comment: `export` is a bash command. Chances are, you don't run sbt on Windows using bash wrapper, so the recipe does not apply to Windows. Most probably, something like `set` may be used in a `.bat` wrapper instead.