# Exception when compiling JasperReport with javascript language

Tags: java, playframework, jasper-reports, rhino, nosuchmethoderror

I'm trying to compile a JasperDesign to create a report programmatically. Since I need to include a Conditional Style in Javascript, I set the JasperDesign language accordingly:

```
val jasperDesign = new JasperDesign
jasperDesign.setLanguage("javascript")
```

**Note that I'm using Scala 2.11 on Java 8, running on Play for Scala 2.5**

Since JasperReports 6.4.3 (the version I'm using) has a dependency on rhino 1.7.6, I added it to the classpath:

```
libraryDependencies += "org.mozilla" % "rhino" % "1.7.6"
```

The problem is that whenever I compile the JasperDesign I get an exception. This happens even when I don't include a Javascript Conditional Style:

> java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   org.mozilla.javascript.ContextFactory.enterContext()Lorg/mozilla/javascript/Context;
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.compilers.JavaScriptClassCompiler.compileUnits(JavaScriptClassCompiler.java:124)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.design.JRAbstractCompiler.compileReport(JRAbstractCompiler.java:203)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compile(JasperCompileManager.java:357)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileToStream(JasperCompileManager.java:326)
>           at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JasperCompileManager.compileReportToStream(JasperCompileManager.java:599)

If I remove `jasperDesign.setLanguage("javascript")` I have no compilation errors. What is missing here? Is there a conflict between Nashorn and Rhino?

Comment: Sounds like you're looking for a version of Rhino at 1.6 or older somewhere on the classpath.  `ContextFactory.enterContext()` was added with 1.7R1.

Comment: Play is using a Rhino based Trireme JavaScript engine (according to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31491931/warning-node-js-detection-failed-sbt-will-use-the-rhino-based-trireme-javascri)), that's probably creating the conflict, I tried adding to sbt `dependencyOverrides ++= Set("org.mozilla" % "rhino" % "1.7.6")` and the problem persists.

Comment: My solution was to take the rhino 1.7.6 jar and manually put it in the application lib folder. Play loaded it from there with no issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was to take the rhino 1.7.6 jar and manually put it in the application lib folder. Play loaded it from there with no issues.